# Azure DevOps: Can we identify Builds triggered from a changeset number?

Tags: azure-devops, azure-devops-rest-api, azure-devops-server-2019

I have certain builds set for Continuous Integration, i.e., build for every check-in. 
I have an automated method to perform code merge and check-ins; now I want to get the list of builds triggered for a particular changeset created. Is there any way we could get this information?

Comment: Do you want to get the info via some kind of script or you need to find the builds via the web interface?

Comment: Basically i want this information to check the build status automatically and roll back the auto-merge for any solution issues. So any information either via API or via web interface would be very much helpful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would use the the REST API so you could check for builds that were run:

```
GET https://dev.azure.com/{organization}/{project}/_apis/build/builds
```

will return all builds that you could then go through and check for more details. You can also have more filters in the request (for example based on the build definition).

The build specifics you could then get via:

```
GET https://dev.azure.com/{organization}/{project}/_apis/build/builds/<buildid>
```

This will return you the infos like:

```
"triggerInfo": {
    "ci.sourceBranch": "refs/heads/master",
    "ci.sourceSha": "0fcb5a27ca2f73561dde0a066a1ec1781128fa81",
    "ci.message": ""
},
...
"sourceBranch": "refs/heads/master",
"sourceVersion": "0fcb5a27ca2f73561dde0a066a1ec1781128fa81",
```

for builds queued from a git repository or

```
{ ...
  "sourceBranch": "$/Build Test",
  "sourceVersion": "93",
... }
```

for TFVC repositories. It actually also would contain a trigger info but I don't have any build around that was triggered automatically based on TFVC.

The `sourceVersion` in git will be the commit hash, where in TFVC it's the changeset.

More details on the REST API can be found in the [Microsoft Docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/build/builds/get?view=azure-devops-rest-5.1)

Comment: Thank you. I think I can query using API. Though the response only shows last 1000 builds in the team project, it solves my purpose of finding the current builds in execution... Thanks again!